# How can I auto map the Z drive

Tags: windows-7

How can I auto map the `Z:` on my client PC that's running Windows 7, to my server that running **Windows Server 2012 R2**?  Path to the Server: `\\Server2\IT tools`

Answer (score 1):

Open GPEdit.msc and open User Configuration, Windows Settings, Scripts so that you can see the Logon, Logoff Scripts.

Put your mapping script in a batch file  (logon.bat)  and put this in

C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\logon

That will run this script at startup / log on.

You might wish to put the disconnect script in a batch file in the Logoff folder.

Answer (score 0):

This will map the `Z:` drive on the Windows 7 machine.

```
net use  z: "\\Server2\IT tools"
```

It would be good to save this in a batch file and put it in the `Startup` folder (e.g `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`) so it runs at startup of the user login process to remap the drive at each logon.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason for not doing so, using Group Policy is the superior solution.